# How to start java service automatically when Centos server starts up

Tags: centos, java, service, startup

I have a server running CentOS, which I am configuring and I would like to have a java service startup automatically when the server is restarted how can I go about doing this?

The command to run the service is:

java -jar testing.jar

this is located in folder /sys/java/service.

Also being new to Linux how can I actually kill the service if I need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the command in 
/etc/rc.local

the best option would be running it as a dedicated user
as in

```
su - username -c "java -jar /sys/java/service/testing.jar"
```

you can kill the service then with

```
pkill -u username java
```